# How to create file with instruction of commands?

Tags: linux, command-line, putty

I have a file name `myFirstFile` that contains certain commands.
But I am not able to excecute them.

If I want to execute this as a program, which code should be implemented?

Comment: You really need to read up on shell scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this file executable* and give it *.sh extention like:
"myFirstFile.sh"

Than run it from terminal (or crontab - it can do things for you when you sleep :) ) like:

```
cd directory/you/have/that/file
sh ./myFirstFile.sh
```

*Im not shure that making it executable is the most secure thing you can do. All my sh scripts are and I never digged into this issue, so make sure its cool

Also make sure you have "#!/bin/bash" in first line - sometimes it helps (dont know why, Google it)

edit: for example my script for starting Minecraf server looks like this

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

BINDIR=$(dirname "$(readlink -fn "$0")")
cd "$BINDIR"

while true
do
    java -Xmx3584M -jar craftbukkit.jar

    echo -e 'If you want to completely stop the server process now, press ctrl-$
    echo "Rebooting in:"
    for i in {5..1}
    do
        echo "$i..."
        sleep 1
    done
    echo 'Restarting now!'
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute your program, it should start with:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

It's the generic script file "header". It indicates that the script is a shell script (if it's bash script you should have `#!/bin/bash`, etc.). If you want to execute it, you should call `chmod +x ./myFirstFile` to give privileges to call it as program, and then you can start your script normally: `./myFirstFile`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the file executable:

```
chmod +x myFirstFile
```

Then you can execute the commands in it:

```
./myFirstFile
```

Comment: thnks.... i am beginner in this language.. actually i have creted it n run the commands successfully...